# toggling a group of icons in gWidgets

Tags: r, icons, handler, gwidgets

Adapting [an example](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/vignettes/gWidgets.pdf) I can toggle the display of an icon like this:

```
reject <- "D:/Pictures/web/close32.png"
accept <- "D:/Pictures/web/open32.png"
w= gwindow()
g1 <- ggroup(horizontal=TRUE, cont=w)
icon <- gimage(reject,cont=g1)
state <- FALSE # a global
changeState <- function(h,...) {
   if(state) {
     svalue(icon) <- reject
     } else {
       svalue(icon) <- accept
       }
   state <<- !state
}
addHandlerClicked(icon, handler=changeState)
```

However, I would like to get this to work with a group of icons
[example 3x3 icon grouping http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/vignettes/gWidgets.pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/vignettes/gWidgets.pdf)
so that each icon can be toggled and I can retrieve the state of the icons as a vector. The purpose is to create a graphical selector for picking pairs of observations to perform analysis on.  Here is my attempt. It displays correctly, but does not respond to clicks to change the state. I recognize that I am confusing how the handler and action parameters act together and would appreciate any clarifications and fixes for this code.

```
reject <- "D:/Pictures/web/close32.png"
accept <- "D:/Pictures/web/open32.png"
w= gwindow()
g1 <- ggroup(horizontal=TRUE, cont=w)
lyt <- glayout(cont=g1, spacing=10)
icon <- rep(reject,times=9)
state <- rep(FALSE, times=9)

changeState <- function(h,...) {
  if(state[index]) {
    svalue(icon[index]) <- reject
  } else {
    svalue(icon[index]) <- accept
  }
  state[index] <<- !state[index]
}

for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in 1:3){
    ind <- (i-1) * 3 +j
    lyt[i,j] <- gimage(icon[ind], cont=lyt)
    addHandlerClicked(lyt[i,j], handler=changeState, action= index <-ind)
  }  
}
```

[1](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gWidgets/vignettes/gWidgets.pdf)c: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kbwK.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index` value must be retrieved from `h$action` in your handler (`index <- h$action`). As well, this bit `action=index <- ind` need only be `action=ind`.

Comment: I have also realized that within the function it is not 'svalue(icon[index])' that gets changed, it should be 'svalue(lyt[i,j])' where action= list(ind,i,j). This ALMOST works, however, when I click on an icon I am getting the error "Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_table_attach: assertion `child->parent == NULL' failed"

Comment: That is just a warning I think, not an error. You should probably just use `h$obj` for the object though, you don't need to look up by index from the global as `h$obj` passes in the receiver of the signal.

Comment: Yes, using h$obj for the object solved the problem. I truly appreciate your help.